# On differentiability of first order ODE on normal form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let the normal form for an ODE be $x'(t)=f(t,x(t))$. I am confused by the notion of differentiability of $f$ w.r.t $x$. Does this mean 
\begin{equation}
\lim \frac{f(t,x(t))-f(t,x(t)+h)}{h} ?
\end{equation}
or does the $h$ go inside the argument of $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposal is correct. However, when considering the function $f$ it is best to think of it as $f(t,x)$ rather than $g(t) = f(t, x(t)) $, since this is a different function.

Comment: So this is in some sense uniformly in $t$ in the second argument? Since we hace sup norm on $\mathcal{C}$

Comment: In the context of the ODE, intuitively you want it so that, as x varies, it's rate of change varies 'smoothly'. This gives x(t) a second derivative wrt t, which may be a desirable property.